# $location is not working in AngularJS Custom Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have custom directive like :

```
angular.module('app.directive').directive('myProductSwitcherDropdown',myProductSwitcherDropdown);

myProductSwitcherDropdown.$inject =  ['$compile'];
 function myProductSwitcherDropdown() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: 'true',
        scope: {
          domainobject:"=",
          ctrlFn:"&"
        },
        templateUrl: "src/directive/templates/my-product-switcher-dropdown.html",

        controller: ['$scope', 'UtilService', function($scope,UtilService) {
            debugger;
            var self = this;
            $scope.instance =self;

            self.dropDownChanged = function(item) {
                debugger;
                $scope.ctrlFn();
            };


        }],
       controllerAs: 'myProductSwitcherDrpdwnCtrl'
  }
}
```

I am invoking the directive like this:

```
<div class='notification-tray'></div>
<div class="left-menu pull-left">
  <my-product-switcher-dropdown domainobject="domainobject" ctrl-fn="ctrlFn()">
  </my-product-switcher-dropdown>
</div>
```

But in my controller, when inside `ctrlFn()` I am tryig to use `say $location or $window` it is coming as **undefined**.

**I HAVE INJECTED THOSE TOO.**

```
angular.module('workspaces.domain').controller('DomainController',DomainController);
DomainController.$inject =  ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location'];
    function DomainController ($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
        var self = this;
        ....
        ....

        //$location is accessible here though 

        $scope.ctrlFn = function () {
            //Undefined here
            debugger;
        };
```

Before `ctrlFn()` `$location` is accessible but inside it's not. **What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: If `$location` is properly injected, there is no reason that it would not be available as a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) in an inner function. I think you are making so many frantic edits to your code that you are confusing yourself. Slow down and take a more methodical approach to debugging your code.

Answer (score 1):

That is an artifact of the Developer Console. The inner code needs to reference `$location` so that the JavaScript engine creates a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures):

```
angular.module('workspaces.domain').controller('DomainController',DomainController);
DomainController.$inject =  ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location'];
    function DomainController ($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
        var self = this;
        ....
        ....

        //$location is accessible here though 

        $scope.ctrlFn = function () {
            //ADD reference to $location
            $location;
            //OR
            console.log($location);
            //Will also be defined here
            debugger;
        };
```

Both methods force the JavaScript engine to create a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) that will be visible to the Developer Console debugger.